# Weak references conundrum

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c-blocks

Suppose I want to create a weak reference so it will not be retained by a block. So I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *myObject;
```

and I do this:

```
__weak typeof(self.myObject) myObjectWeak = self.myObject;

void (^doSomething)() = ^void() {
   [myObjectWeak doSomething];    
};
```

but what about this:

```
__weak typeof(self) selfWeak = self;

void (^doSomething)() = ^void() {
   [selfWeak.myObject doSomething];    
};
```

Will this produce the same effect? I mean having a weak reference to myObject inside the block? I suspect it is not, but I just need to confirm.

Comment: sorry about that, I had a typo on my question. I meant `selfWeak.myObject` not `selfWeak.myObjectWeak`. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Thanks. Please transform this comment into an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `selfWeak` in that last example is sufficient to break the strong reference cycle. Don't worry about the fact that you reference its properties in there.